# gtmetrix.com errors: The following image(s) are missing width and/or height attributes

Tags: image, attributes, width

When I run my site at gtmetrix.com, I get errors that say "The following image(s) are missing width and/or height attributes."  This happened with several images within my site, and I fixed those.  But I'm also getting errors for external links, for example:

http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/cb_scout2.png (Dimensions: 1028 x 214) (4 uses)
http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/mv/imgs8.png (Dimensions: 68 x 67) (3 uses)
http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@269000000&src=apiv3&hl=en-US&x=31140&y=49979&z=17&style=47,37%7Csmartmaps

Is there any way to add the width/height on these images?

Thanks!!